# Google is crawling my website but not indexing any pages

Tags: google-search

I own the website http://ecservice.ro. I have added keyword description and everything any tutorial said but it looks like google is refusing to index any of my pages. `site:ecservice.ro` works but keyword searches no result.. I went to all the pages.. and didn't find any result..

If anyone can help me I will really appreciate it..

P.S.
Not looking to get in the first page of the search.. But for now.. just show on any page.. and will work from there...

Comment: The fact that your `site:` search works indicates that you are indexed by Google.

Comment: Do SEO stuff to improve your ranking in Google results because your website is young.

Answer (score 1):

Search results are based, in part, on content and how many other sites link to yours. New sites can take a while before they build up a reputation among the thousands of other similar sites. Your site, however, is filled with unrelated links to other(?) pages like cleaning services and search engines (and myself) will consider your site nothing but spam. That is why you, hopefully, will never show up in search results.

Comment: did you atleast read the content of the page.. i think the text is right on the money as the webpage is for my business not information.

Comment: @SerbanStefanitaGabriel - I did not translate it till now but stuffing your page with keywords like that will get red flagged by Google and other search engines every time as spam.

Comment: I understand.. just saw that many pages have some keywords there.. i didn`t hide them and i was thinking that google will not mind them there... i will remove them.. and try to add them in another way.. Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for [Google Webmasters](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and then submit a site map.  Google will then show you what links you have submitted, as well as what links Google has indexed.  Note that it does take a while for Google to index your submitted sitemap.

[image: Here are the stats from my site]

Comment: i did that and it said 7 links submitted and 6 indexed but when i click on "index status" it says Total indexed : 0

Comment: Once you submit the sitemap, it will take some time for Google to index your pages. It took about 2 - 3 weeks for my 3 pages to show up as indexed. YMMV.